# MarkDown ( Dont format my TEXT from Database )

Tags: php, mysql, database, server, markdown

I'm a very new in this field.
I need to put MarkDown in my site.

I'm using this: https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor

MarkDown appears and works CLIENT SIDE, with PREVIEW I see HTML formatted.

The problem is when I send text to the database, and after getting this and printing it in my page.

Database is in SQL, type is a VARCHAR.

HTML is not formated.

Information:

- Server : XAMPP ( Apache ) Windows
- Language : PHP , Javascript/JQuery
- MarkDown : https://github.com/NextStepWebs/simplemde-markdown-editor

I think that takes something in Server Side, but I can't find anything on github.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about this: "To print i use `.row`."? Perhaps show the code which outputs (prints?) the post content.

Comment: @Waylan what sense have? BUT Ok , UP .

Comment: @Master-Antonio you actually need to post your full code for printing - because what you've written won't run. After `$i++` you should have an `echo` statement.

Comment: @icc97 , yes i forgot. However this is the full code, There are just repetitions of the first, but with the class changed. But this is not the problem, the problem is a other. "when I send text to the database, and after getting this and printing it in my page , html is not formated " , example, in markdown there is ### Hello , in preview i see Hello in <h3> but print in my card ### Hello .

Comment: you're printing out directly from the database - so it means that you are saving Markdown to your database and not HTML. So you need to run the same code that you do for the preview on the Markdown that comes out of the database

Comment: Side note: I hope you aren't injecting your raw user data into your SQL statement, as your code snippet seems to suggest... Whatever, don't waste your time learning a database library that's deprecated and about to be removed.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario What? Where? Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have a working preview on the client which accepts Markdown text and successfully converts it to HTML and displays it in a preview. However, now you want to store the text in a database.

If you ever expect to come back to it later to edit the text, then you will always want to store the document as Markdown text. That means that every time the page is requested/displayed, the text will also need to be converted from Markdown to HTML. However, when the document is retrieved from the database and before it is served up to the client, you need to run the document through a Markdown parser to convert it to HTML. My PHP is a little rusty, but something like the following change will get you started in the right direction:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        $i=0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            $i++;
            echo ' <div class="comment">'.Markdown::defaultTransform($row ['contenuto']).'</div> ext ext ext '
        }
```

Notice that the content obtained from the database is passed though a [Markdown parser](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) before being printed.  You will need to properly install a PHP Markdown library for it to work. Of course, the Markdown will be parsed every time the page is requested.

An alternative solution might be to use a JavaScript Markdown parser (perhaps the same one used by the preview tool) which would convert the Markdown to HTML on the client each time the page is requested. However, that would assume that each request is only requesting a partial document (perhaps with an AJAX request) rather than loading an entire new page (otherwise how will the JavaScript library be available to process the document). This may or may not work, again depending on your current setup, and is generally not the preferred option. Another answer provides a potential solution of this sort.

A third (and perhaps more attractive) option, which could eliminate the need to convert the Markdown to HTML on each request, would be to store both the raw Markdown text and the converted HTML text as two separate columns in your database table. That way, when you want to "edit" the document, retrieve the Markdown document and make your changes. When those changes are saved, save both the Markdown and the rendered HTML to their respective database columns. However, when you want to display the document (which would probably happen most of the time) retrieve the document from the rendered column of the database (the HTML). For example:

```
$HTMLpost = Markdown::defaultTransform($post);
```

Comment: The environment you are using: server, language, framework (if any), and possibly the code you are using to get/save the data to the database. The slightest variation in any of those could completely change the specifics of the answer. No one is going to give you an answer without knowing all that stuff as the answer will be completely useless unless they happen to guess correctly, which is not very likely.

Comment: Up the post. See. Thanks to all.

Comment: I've added some code examples and explanations now that I have more info.

Comment: This is only Server Side , right? Can use My Markdown? Or is necessary use also this for Client Side?

Comment: Class 'Markdown' not found . Work Markdown () no Markdown::defaultTransform().

Comment: Yes this is server side. Did you install the Markdown library I linked to? It will not work if you don't.

Comment: Yes Yes. I replied you . Work Markdown () no Markdown::defaultTransform().

Answer (score 0):

simplemde-markdown-editor uses [Marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) to convert the Markdown to HTML for the preview.

So you just need to follow the code in the Marked readme: https://github.com/chjj/marked#browser

```
<?php
if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    $i = 0;

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $i++;
        $comment = $row['contenuto'];
        echo "<div id='comment$i' class='comment'></div>
        <script>
        document.getElementById('comment$i').innerHTML = marked('$comment');
        </script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Client Side can use My Markdown? Or is necessary use also this?

Comment: This is run on the server side which generates javascript that is then run client side. This will generate HTML on the client side. If you also want to display the markdown on the client side then just `echo $row['contenuto']`